# Field not writable: ContentVersion.FileType

Tags: apex, unit-test, contentversion

In the following test method:

```
    static testMethod void testEmailWithAttachments() {
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
        contentVersion.FileType = 'Text';
        contentVersion.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
        contentVersion.Title = 'Test';
        insert contentVersion;
    }
```

I receive:

> Field is not writeable: ContentVersion.FileType

Please advise how to avoid `Field is not writeable: ContentVersion.FileType` and make the insert in my test method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FileType` isn't writeable, but `PathOnClient` is - it's createable, but not updateable. The system will infer the type of file from the pathname extension you supply in that field. (`ContentNote` records will have type `SNOTE`; they don't have extensions).

See the [SOAP Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm):

> FileType is defined by either ContentUrl for links or PathOnClient for documents, but not both.